# What is to be the resolution of button for all drawable folder in android?

Tags: android, button, resolution

Button which i created for my app is of resolution 166*169. But it doesn't look perfect on my app when placed directly from drawable folder. So i created other drawable folders, but what is to be the resolution among them doesn't know. I do google that but nothing find which is relevant to me.

Comment: Make your page design with 720*1280 resolution then cut all icon and paste it to drawable-xhdpi folder. It looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different png files for different drawables such as hdpi or mdpi.  I recommend you do use 9-patch images.  It is simple now that you can use a 9-patch generator, just put your image it will generate 9-patch images for all your drawable folders and you just need to import them.

Comment: You can use the generator from this link: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example  or just google for android simple nine-patch generator.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SVG** instead of **PNG** or **JPEG** in drawable, android support svg and this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/) will help you